# I can not use redim preserve in some parts of the code

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am using redim preserve to store objects but an error occurs.
In the part of the code where I need to use it the program breaks.

```
function get_info(ByRef a_array_of_objects )

'ReDim Preserve a_array_of_opbjects ( 5 )  if i put here the redim 
 'preserve it works but i don`t need here

Set conexion = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set comando =Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
conexion.open "DSN=mydsn;server=myserver;uid=myUser;pwd=mypass"
comando.ActiveConnection=conexion       

comando.CommandText="MY_STORE_PROCEDURE"
comando.CommandType=4

comando.Parameters.Append objComm1.CreateParameter("p_parameter",3,1,100,10)

set v_local=comando.Execute

v_local_array=v_local.GetRows

 ReDim Preserve a_array_of_objects ( ubound(v_local_array,2) ) '  i need 
   'here the redim preserve code but it breaks      
   ' the index is out of range is the error
 for i=0  to  UBound(v_local_array,2)
   set o_object=new c_object

   o_object.let_property=v_local_array(0,i)
   o_object.let_property1=v_local_array(1,i)

   a_array_of_objects(i)=o_object 
next




function_that_clean_parameters(comando)
conexion.close  

    'ReDim Preserve a_array_of_objects ( 10) here the code don`t works also

 end function
```

I expected to get the fix of objects but I get an error message
If someone can helpe me.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe there is a restriction of the programming language, because I do not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to pass an array by reference. You won't be able to use `ReDim` if the array is locked. You will need to pass it by value:

```
function get_info(ByVal a_array_of_objects)
```

The reason you're able to `ReDim` the array at the start of your function is because you misspelt it:

> a_array_of_o**p**bjects

You were creating a new array rather than ReDimming the one being passed.

Also, your function isn't actually returning anything, at the end of your function make sure to include:

```
get_info = a_array_of_objects
```

Comment: I underestand your comment but i have some little code that does the same thing, i pass the array for reference and use redim in the function and it`s works. And the second comment a_array_of_o p bjects it was an error when i pasted the code, i changed the original names for it can underestand.

Comment: My function do not return anything because i am passing the array for reference.I have another little code that does something like that : it to receive an array for reference and redim it, then put 3 objects in it and "returned" the array with the objects. Its works, the diference is that my 
test function don`t connect to the data base. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: That makes sense. I just assumed you were getting a lock error from trying to pass the array by reference whilst it was still open. What error message are you getting?

Comment: the message is "The subscript is out of range".

Comment: @Patricio On the `a_array_of_objects(i)=o_object` line?

Comment: I went back to programming in asp a short time ago but there are things that I do not get used to. The error is not the passage by reference of the arrangement. The error is that in my function "main" the name of the variable with which I call the function get_info is the same as that of the local variable.
Something like: get_info (v_local_array)

Comment: The line was  ReDim Preserve a_array_of_objects ( ubound(v_local_array,2) ).          Thanks for your help and sorry for the lost time

Comment: That error would indicate that the array being passed to the function is 2 dimensional (or more). You can't use `ReDim` AND `Preserve` on a 2D array, you can only use ReDim. Also, in your loop you're assigning values to the array as if it were 1D. Plus, you appear to be overwriting its values anyway, so I can't see why you're choosing to preserve it.

Comment: That i underestand that occurs because i called lthe function like that get_info(v_local_array) and then 
the name of my function call variable (being by reference) has a conflict with the name of the local variable and the dimensions of the arrays are confused.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the array being passed by reference shares the same name as an array within your function, but if the referenced array is multi-dimensional you will need to drop the `preserve` and amend your code accordingly.

Comment: @Adam You can use `Redim Preserve` on a 2D array (or more), but you can only adjust the **last** dimension of the array - all the others must remain fixed

Comment: @Dave absolutely right, not sure why the other comment got upvoted it’s completely wrong. Use `ReDim` and `Preserve` to populate 2D Arrays all the time.

Comment: I think I once read somewhere that preserve can only be used with 1D arrays, but I guess that was a lie. Oh well, you live and you learn!